# Memory Allocation and GC in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jvm

I am using tomcat-7 and java-8 with spring framework. I just deployed an application in webapps. After that, I monitored memory in visualvm, Below is the screenshot.

[image]

There is no hit on tomcat and used heap is increasing and after a limit GC performed.
I want to know, If this is normal behaviour or something wrong with my web application.

Comment: Yes it is normal behavior. Just for information, what is the vm arguments you are passing? I guess -xms looks like 500mb?

Comment: You could constraint  the heap with `-Xmx`.

Comment: There are no hits on Tomcat, but there is still some minor background processing going on that will allocate objects on the heap.  After what looks like 5 minutes, the GC decided to clean those up.

Comment: visualvm monitoring itself can increase object allocation rate substantially; check the output of "jstat -gc <vm id> 1000 1000" with and then without visualvm attached (EU column is of the most interest)

Comment: @starikoff Thanks. That's a great help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is how a healthy application memory usate should looks like.

> The reason for the double-sawtooth pattern is that the JVM needs to allocate memory on the heap as new objects are created as a part of the normal program execution. Most of these objects are short-lived and quickly become garbage. These short-lived objects are collected by a collector called “Minor GC” and represent the small drops on the sawteeth

https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/memory-leaks-fallacies-and-misconceptions