# Why Tomcat server shows such a sawtooth graph even at rest?

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

Even if I didn't deploy anything under the webapps directory, my tomcat (apache-tomcat-8.5.63) server shows the heap memory usage here below.

In my opinion 700 MB of memory seems to much for background tasks and at the same time using the `jstat -gc <vm id> 1000 1000` command with and without `visualvm` attached, as suggested here ([Memory Allocation and GC in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828287/memory-allocation-and-gc-in-tomcat)), doesn't change anything.

My question is: how could I understand which objects tomcat it's allocating and how to avoid it?

Simply dumping heap memory doesn't provide me a clear understanding, while simply acting on `xmx` and `xms` parameters wouldn't solve this issue on the long run.

[image]

**UPDATE**

After 24h the situation is the following, I was wondering IF this memory allocation is due to monitoring tools (only) running in the background or not and why the peaks are visibly descending?

[image]

Comment: "Too much" would be allocating 700MB per second. Allocating 700 MB in 40 minutes is nothing to worry about, if all this memory is then garbage collected. Anyway, you may use an [allocation profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) to find what exactly is allocated and where it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

700MB are allocate *over time* for background operation, because there is enough free memory to not trigger garbage collection. As it seems that all of the memory can be freed again, there's no need to worry or optimize anything: It's just doing its job, and the memory is freed when necessary (just not before it's either necessary, or before some time is up)

It would be worth worrying about something, if the low point of the sawtooth would steadily go up after each GC run: That *could* signal a memory leak (if indeed the system is idle). But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Edit after your additional diagram in the question, and the numerous comments:

Tomcat's memory consumption with nothing else running is constant, as can be observed by the bottom of the sawtooth pattern being on a horizontal line. The frequency and height of the sawtooth depend on when the JVM's GC kicks in, and also is nothing to worry about. I've given some samples of what's happening in the background in the comments - these samples are not meant to be encyclopedic. They're incomplete.

For a full list of the background activities, analyze the source code - such an analysis goes far beyond the scope of an answer on stackoverflow.

Nothing to worry here. Carry on

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thus my question would be: why is tomcat allocating all these resources and what these resources are roughly meant for?

Comment: There are several pools of objects that need to be checked frequently - e.g. database connections (the connections might have timed out, and Tomcat might be configured to always have active connections ready). Sessions time out after a while - that might be checked every minute or so. Tomcat is a complex piece of software, so I'll only give some example of these operations.

Comment: Thanks  lot for your examples (I was asking for!), but e.g. Tomcat might want to have db connections ready even if the `webapps` directory is empty and nothing is deployed on it? I removed `ROOT`, `manager`, `host-manager`, `examples` and `docs` too, inside it.

Comment: Most notably, gathering these statistics and sending them to VisualVM itself requires memory. So even with an application doing nothing at all, as soon as you connect with VisualVM, you will see a steady amount of allocations over time.

Comment: Ok, I already read about it, but I got surprised by the fact that measuring performance could affects performances themselves such a way! In fact, depending on where the tomcat is installed I observed that the allocated memory can sometimes hit several gigs - steadily - always with this sawtooth profile.

Comment: Just a side note about the `observational error` pertinent to this situation: "Could we question whether or not this tools (VisualVM, jMonitor, etc ...) [accuracy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) is acceptable or not?"

Comment: There is **nothing to worry** about. Even if Tomcat hits several gigs, that's just a sign that GC doesn't kick in **because it's not necessary**. This is also _not a performance issue_, because GC will be quick with so many long unused objects. Memory consumption is not necessarily tied to performance (especially when measured over such a long time). As there's nothing to worry about, I'd say the accuracy of these tools is absolutely enough to measure something as irrelevant as this. (plus: see my edits to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add what I've learned till now: using [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/overhead.jsp) seemed to have less overhead and thus a minor footprint on the JVM heap memory usage.

The plot here below in fact, became a straight line as soon as I turned off VisualVM and monitored the empty Tomcat server with YourKit solely, remotely. Then, once GC is triggered the memory usage drops down and approximately remains constants (slightly increasing thought), thus demonstrating the sawtooth profile was just matter of profiler's **overhead**.

[image]
[image]
[image]